# Omit cases conditionally

Tags: r

My data are as follows:

```
data <- structure(list(animal.ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), treatment = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", 
"D", "A", "C", "A", "A","A", "C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

I would like to omit animal.ID's that NEVER occur in treatment B. My desired output is as follows:

```
data <- structure(list(animal.ID = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), treatment = c("C", "D", "A", "C", "A", "A","A", "C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Base R

```
subset(data, ave(treatment !='B', animal.ID, FUN = all))

   animal.ID treatment
5          2         C
6          2         D
7          2         A
8          2         C
9          3         A
10         3         A
11         3         A
12         3         C
```

Using tidyverse:

```
library(dplyr) # version>=1.1.0
filter(data, all(treatment!='B'), .by = animal.ID)

  animal.ID treatment
1         2         C
2         2         D
3         2         A
4         2         C
5         3         A
6         3         A
7         3         A
8         3         C
```

in older versions:

```
data %>%
   group_by(animal.ID) %>%
   filter(all(treatment != 'B'))
```